# Cross-site publishing - using SharePoint "My Site" as authoring site collection?

Tags: 2013, my-site, cross-site-publishing

I'm planning to use the SharePoint 2013 cross-site publishing feature to isolate content authoring from content publishing. My use case is business intelligence scenario, where mostly it will be Excel reports or other office documents that will be authored. So the Power users will be the content authors.

**Question**: Is it possible to use the Power users "My Site" as authoring site collections and push the authored contents (i.e. Excel reports) to a publishing site collection? Because "My Site" is actually just another site collection so it should be possible, I'm just wondering will there be any limitations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can you: probably yes**
i can see no technical reasons for why not, but haven't triede it.

**Should you: probably not**
Remember that cross site publishing doesn't move the content, just information about it.

So you'll store these documents in the My sites.

In my opinion it would break the spirit of the "My Site" as a storage place and playground for the individual person. The information you want to share sounds role specific not person specific. What happens if a person moves to another role within the company, how do you transfer ownership to the reports in her My Site to the new person responsible for them?

How do you transfer the documents when changes in responsibility happens?

What happens when a person leaves the company?

**Remember that by default the My Site is deleted automatically 14 days after the person is renoved from User Profile, which probably is set up to be when they are removed from AD.**

In my opinion it would be better to create one (or more) site collections dedicated to the information.

Comment: Can't argue with that :)

Comment: True it is role specific. Thanks for the reply, that gave me an idea for the approach. I lean towards separate site collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Cross site publishing utilizes search and the content search web parts for aggregating content from designated catalogs. Cross site publishing odes take some work to configure however -it's not just a single feature you turn on and start using.